# Relearning C: New idioms?

Tags: c, idioms

I'm relearning C after not having touched it since 2000 or so.  I've been working in Ruby since then, and I discovered a whole world of programming idioms I never knew existed.

What important C techniques, books, idioms, etc. have arisen in the past decade, if any? I know about the C99 and C11 standards, but where else should I be looking? Or has C style remained constant even as OOP and FP have become the norm?

Comment: This is a tricky question to answer.  I can't remember what programming was like 10 years ago!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is [constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)... Interesting question though, so I'm not flagging.

Comment: Designated initializers has probably been the most significant development in C99.

Comment: Declaration inside `for` loops, as in: `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) /* ... */;`

Comment: I would advise to rewrite the question in the more generic format of "what has happend in the C language during the past 10 years" and then post it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com. It will likely receive a warmer welcome there.

Comment: Lundin: Yes, you are right.. my bad.  Joe: There are standards now?

Comment: Re-asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135582/whats-new-in-c-idioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't support *at language level* nothing more than procedural programming - and that's a precise choice, because it was born to be mostly a "portable assembly" and it's used to work as tightly close to the machine as possible (without resorting to assembly). 
Most assembly languages do not provide much more, in terms of programming paradigms, than a stack and function call statement (some micros not even that) - and that's what C is modeled upon.

After all, there's a reason why C++ and Objective C were born: C has to keep its design philosophy, and to add more abstract stuff people had to actually fork the language.

That being said, there's nothing stopping you to write e.g. OO code in C - actually, many people do that (I'd say that it's one of the most diffused idioms in C), but you don't have to expect almost any syntax sugar for that: you'll have to use `struct`s for the data, "normal" functions to "emulate" methods, composition for inheritance, pointer tables for polymorphism, and so on. Still, I don't know if this counts as a "last decade" idiom, it is being used since much longer.

Comment: that's what makes it great. no anti-patterns included. or patterns. just the tool to create it all yourself.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech: switching between C++ and Python for a project I saw by myself that when you need to experiment a quicker language with its patterns and its stuff ready-made is a great choice, but when you have to make it run *fast* and/or build a solution perfectly tailored to your needs it's often better a language that give you tools without forcing anything. As usual, the choice of the right tool depends from what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Joseph: However, it lacks functionality like tail call optimization guarantees that effectively prevents you from implementing certain kinds of patterns.

Comment: @NiklasB.: well, almost any decent C compiler in the last 20 years implemented tail call optimization; still, the interesting thing is that almost any higher level language that has been written in the last two decades has been written in C - which tells you that *it is* possible to build all the higher level stuff in C - although sometimes you have to implement a whole new language. :)

Comment: @Matteo: Yeah, well in that sense every two turing-complete languages are more or less equivalent (because one can be implemented using the other).

Comment: Every new language seems to make the same mistake of implementing the fashionable anti-patterns of their day rather than just creating the tried and test design patterns as part of their language. and even then some patterns are so easy to implement without being keywords in a language that implementing those should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

It varies by culture, and it's really not evolved as much as other languages I use. I've seen:

- more type safety
- better tooling
- 32/64 bit compatible code and fixed width types
- libraries, notably POSIX
- more object oriented

not exactly new idioms for every point -- as far as the way programs are constructed and approached, these are some of the more noticeable changes at the source level.